# Talend - Snowflake : tDBOutput UPSERT / UPDATE doesn't update data

Tags: java, talend

I have 2 tables one DWH that contains the data that needs to be insert / updated and ODS that contains the latest unprocessed data.

Here is the DDL of the two tables :

- ODS

  create or replace TABLE ODS.ATT_HFSQL_ETTCTCP (
  CTCSOC VARCHAR(5),
  CTCAGE VARCHAR(5),
  CTCCLI VARCHAR(10),
  CTCAFF VARCHAR(10),
  CTCMAN VARCHAR(16777216),
  CTCCHG VARCHAR(10),
  CTCCDE VARCHAR(10),
  CTCLIG VARCHAR(10),
  CTCSLI VARCHAR(10),
  CTCPAG VARCHAR(10),
  CTCPER VARCHAR(10),
  CTCCTR VARCHAR(10),
  CTCAVE VARCHAR(10),
  CTCQUA VARCHAR(10),
  CTCPON VARCHAR(10),
  CTCPOE VARCHAR(10),
  CTCPOC VARCHAR(10),
  CTCMOT VARCHAR(20),
  CTCACT VARCHAR(10),
  CTCTER VARCHAR(20),
  CTCDEB VARCHAR(20),
  CTCFIN VARCHAR(20),
  CTCREL VARCHAR(20),
  CTCXFI VARCHAR(20),
  CTCXF2 VARCHAR(20),
  CTCFMO VARCHAR(20),
  CTCDAV VARCHAR(20),
  CTCFII VARCHAR(20),
  CTCFPV VARCHAR(20),
  CTCHRE VARCHAR(10),
  CTCESS VARCHAR(10),
  CTCDUR VARCHAR(10),
  CTCSAL VARCHAR(10),
  CTCSNH VARCHAR(10),
  CTCCOE VARCHAR(10),
  CTCSTA VARCHAR(10),
  CTCJOD VARCHAR(10),
  CTCJOF VARCHAR(10),
  CTCTYC VARCHAR(10),
  CTCCAT VARCHAR(10),
  CTCFBU VARCHAR(10),
  CTCREF VARCHAR(100),
  CTCMEX VARCHAR(10),
  CTCDUE VARCHAR(10),
  CTCCD3 VARCHAR(20),
  DATCRE VARCHAR(20),
  DATMOD VARCHAR(20),
  DATE_CHARGEMENT TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)
  );
- DWH

  create or replace TABLE PRD_DWH_SOFINORD.ATT.ATT_CONTRAT (
  CD_SOCIETE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  CD_AGENCE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  NUM_CONTRAT_TT VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  CD_CLIENT VARCHAR(10),
  CD_SITE VARCHAR(10),
  CD_CHARGE_AFFAIRE VARCHAR(10),
  NUM_MATRICULE_TT VARCHAR(10),
  CD_QUALIF VARCHAR(10),
  CD_MOTIF_DEBUT VARCHAR(10),
  CD_TERME VARCHAR(10),
  DT_DEBUT_CONTRAT DATE,
  DT_FIN_CONTRAT DATE,
  HE_DEBUT_CONTRAT TIME(9),
  DT_AVENANT DATE,
  NB_ESSAI NUMBER(38,0),
  MT_SALAIRE_REF FLOAT,
  NB_HEURE_REF FLOAT,
  NB_HEURE_HEBDO FLOAT,
  CD_TYPE_CONTRAT VARCHAR(10),
  CD_ACTIVITE VARCHAR(10),
  CD_MOTIF_FIN VARCHAR(10),
  DT_FIN_REEL DATE,
  DT_DPAE DATE,
  NUM_COMMANDE VARCHAR(100),
  NUM_COMMANDE_INTERNE VARCHAR(10),
  TX_COEFF FLOAT,
  CD_STATUT VARCHAR(10),
  DT_CREATION DATE,
  DT_MODIFICATION DATE,
  CD_SOURCE VARCHAR(10),
  DT_CHARGEMENT TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9),
  constraint PK_ATT_CONTRAT primary key (CD_SOCIETE, CD_AGENCE, NUM_CONTRAT_TT)
  );

I have a simple job that 'SELECT' the data from the ODS and UPSERT it in the DWH :

[image]

And for the configuration of the tDBOutput component (it is configured for UPSERT) :

[image]

And the schema in input of the tDBOutput :

[image]

So now in the DWH I have a row with the key : CD_SOCIETE = '006' AND CD_AGENCE = 'F15' AND NUM_CONTRAT_TT = '201518' and when I check in the DWH table I have for example a DT_MODIFICATION column set at  : 2023-09-15 and in the incoming data with the row with the same key :

[image]

I have the new data for the same field : 2023-11-09

And after the execution I have no errors, reject but the data isn't updated :

[image]

And here is the expected data :

[image]

I have no clue why the update isn't happening.

Comment: Check if the Snowflake connection is AUTOCOMMIT ON.

Comment: Hi I checked, for all of our Snowflake connections the AutoCommit is checked by default